# SVG fade color of object

Tags: svg, fade

I want to fade the fill color of a svg circle from one color to another color, like from red to black.

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" fade-to="black"/>
</svg>
```

What would I do in place of the `fade-to="black"`?

Comment: What do you mean by "fade"? Would you like a gradient from red to black or is it fading over time, like the red changing to black over 2 seconds, maybe triggered by an event (user clicking something etc.)

Comment: @chrwahl it is fading over time, like the red changing to black over 2 seconds, maybe triggered by an event (user clicking something etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the radial gradient to have this work. You can play around with the offset numbers for the desired effect.

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="myGradient">
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="black" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>

  <!-- using my radial gradient -->
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="url('#myGradient')"/>
</svg>
```

Hope this helps!

Edit***:
After doing some more research and figuring out how to do what you were suggesting, this is what I came up with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    .redBall{
        fill: red;
        z-index: 1;
        -webkit-animation: pulsateMore 3s ease-out;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes pulsateMore {
        0% { 
        fill: red;
        }
        50% { 
        fill: black;
        }
        00% { 
        fill: red;
        }
    }
    </style>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> -->
</head>
<body>
    <svg height="100" width="100">
        <circle class="redBall" cx="50" cy="50" r="40"/>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

You can manipulate this code from here to have a Javascript function that will have an onClick event that will trigger the circle to go from red to black, instead of pulsating. If this has helped you, please accept the answer, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not looking for a gradient, but however, I am looking for a solution where when a user clicks a button, the red circle fades to black.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you just need to change the circle's `fill` attribute either with:

- css (e.g :hover)
- svg SMIL animation (using `begin="click"`)
- javaScript (e.g. click eventListner)

```js
let dotJs = document.querySelector('#dotJs');

dotJs.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
circle {
  transition: 0.5s fill;
}

.active {
  fill: #000
}

#dotCSS:hover {
  fill: #000
}
```

```html
<p>Css hover</p>
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <circle id="dotCSS" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>

<p>JS click</p>
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <circle id="dotJs" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>

<p>SMIL click</p>
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <circle id="dot" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
      <animate id="startAnimation"
               href="#dot" 
               attributeName="fill" 
               from="red" 
               to="black" 
               begin="click"
               dur="0.5s" 
               repeatCount="0"
               fill="freeze"
/>
</svg>
```

Check [Mike Harris' post: Toggling SVG without any scripting](https://codepen.io/mikemjharris/post/svg-toggling) for a more advanced svg only example.